# Sed sliding window replace

Tags: regex, sed

I'm wrote the below `sed` to unquote the numbers from csv,

```
sed  -E 's|,"(-?[0-9]*.?[0-9]*)",|,\1,|g'
```

When I experimented with the below expression,

```
echo '"a","1.2","1.77",'|sed  -E 's|,"(-?[0-9]*.?[0-9]*)",|,\1,|g'
```

The result was this,

> "a",1.2,"1.77",

Though there are problems with this specific regex in the context of replacing the digits in the first and last column. My exact concern here is to know if there a way to make sed work in a sliding window manner?

Comment: Since double quoted strings within double quoted strings will need to be quoted by `\ `, perhaps `sed -E 's/"([0-9.+-]+)"/\1/g' file` is suffice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In GNU `sed`, you may use

```
sed -E ':a; s/(,|^)"(-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)"(,|$)/\1\2\3/g; ta' <<< '"a","1.2","1.77",'
# => "a",1.2,1.77,
```

In FreeBSD `sed`, use `-e` to append commands:

```
sed -E -e ':a' -e 's/(,|^)"(-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)"(,|$)/\1\2\3/g' -e 'ta'
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/iir32Z)

**Details**

- `:a` - sets an `a` label
- `s/(,|^)"(-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)"(,|$)/\1\2\3/g` - finds all occurrences of the `(,|^)"(-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)"(,|$)` pattern that matches

  - `(,|^)` - Group 1: comma or start of string
  - `"` - a double quotation mark
  - `(-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)` - Group 2: an optional `-`, 0+ digits, and optional decimal separator, 1+ digits
  - `"` - a double quotation mark
  - `(,|$)` - Group 3: comma or end of string

     and replaces with Group 1, Group 2 and Group 3 values
- `ta` - jumps to the `a` label position upon a successful substitution.

Note that a literal dot in the pattern should be escaped, otherwise, it matches any character.

Comment: for some reason, it is not working in my macOS terminal. Which shell have u tried? I tried with both zsh and bash.

Comment: @KannanRamamoorthy The initial demo is in GNU `sed`. In FreeBSD `sed`, try `sed  -E -e ':a' -e 's/(,|^)"(-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)"(,|$)/\1\2\3/g' -e 'ta' <<< '"a","1.2","1.77",'`